# Powershell Output inconsistencies

Tags: powershell, csv, output

I have a powershell script that works just fine when I open powershell manually and run the script. It produces an output like such:

```
10.52.30.131    BALL-AIRKYYCP0      Not installed    Ping successful    Windows
10.52.30.133    BALL-4FNRAMLOD      Not installed    Ping successful    Windows
10.52.30.134    BALL-5UU20W8E2      Not installed    Ping successful    Windows
```

If I right click the script file and then click run in powershell the script runs fine and does everything it needs to do but the output returned is different, see below:

```
10.52.30.131    BALL-AIRKYYCP0  Not installed    Ping successful    Wind
ows             
10.52.30.133    BALL-4FNRAMLOD  Not installed    Ping successful    Wind
ows             
10.52.30.134    BALL-5UU20W8E2  Not installed    Ping successful    Wind
ows
```

For some reason running it by right click 'Run in Powershell' causes the output to be messy and cells to be cut off and finished on the next row. This is a small sample

Any ideas why the output would be different when running the script this way?

Comment: Are the widths of the console windows different?

Comment: That was the issue, set to auto resize window in script. Thanks Nate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the console windows were different sizes depending how you were launching it.

You can set your console window size from within your Powershell script if you want, using `get-host`.

For example, this will set the width of the console to 120:

```
$ws = (get-host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize
$ws.Width = 120
(get-host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize = $ws
```

Got this technique from here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee156814.aspx